# Is there something I'm missing in my key listener/key event section which is preventing the sprite from moving in Java

Tags: java, keylistener, void, keyevent, keycode

I am trying to get a sprite to move and despite there being no errors that come up it still doesn't move the sprite even though i cant find any issues with it. It may be something I'm missing or shouldn't be there but any advice is appreciated

I've tried changing the key codes (VK_RIGHT etc) and yet none of the changes seem to affect it and make it work. I am using the eclipse work space so I'm not sure if it could be that

Game page

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) player.right = true;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) player.left = true;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) player.up = true;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) player.down = true;
```

Player page

```
public boolean right,left,up,down;
private int speed = 4;

public Player(int x,int y) {
    setBounds(x,y,32,32);
}
public void tick() {
    if(right)x+=speed;
    if(left)x-=speed;
    if(up)y-=speed;
    if(down)y+=speed;
}
```

I am expecting the player to move on the screen in the direction corresponding to the direction of the key pressed but nothing happens and it doesn't move at all

Comment: Do you ever set fields `left`, `right`, `up`, `down` to `false`?

Comment: Is your class implementing this interface `public interface KeyListener`

Comment: Do you call tick()?

Comment: Changing you variables is not enough. You'd need to redraw the "screen world" in order to reflect the new game state / variables value change

Comment: When you set one to `true` you need to set the 3 others to `false`

Comment: I tried setting them to false and nothing changed, I tried calling tick but it said that there cant be 2 instances of tick in game, and setting the other 3 to false doesn't change anything

Comment: Also what is meant by redrawing the "screen world"